# What happens if a Grappled creature makes Grab attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple

When two creatures are locked in a [Grapple](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Grappled), the defender can, on its turn, make a full-attack.

Assuming that creature has [Grab](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Grab_Ex) (and assuming its attacks land), what happens? Does it get to make free grapple attempts to reverse the grapple, or free itself?

What if that creature also has [Constrict](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Constrict_Ex)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attacks land, the creature would have the opportunity to initiate a grapple, with itself as the controlling grappler.
Since the roll is the same (CMB vs CMD) both for initiating a new grapple and to become the dominant grappler, when already grappling, the only difference is that the creature can deal damage before attempting the grapple.

Constrict lets you deal damage when succeeding a grapple check. Initiating a grapple is a success and so is becoming the dominant grappler as such it wouldn't matter if it was made with [Grap](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Grab_Ex) or trying to control the grapple.